# Why doesn't "onload" work on a <circle> element?

Tags: javascript, function, svg, onclick, onload

Code:

```
      <circle id="whitecircle" cx="500" cy="500" r="25" fill="url(#grad1)" onclick="setCoordinates(evt)"  />
```

This works perfectly well. "setCoordinates(evt)" function gives the circle a random position when it is clicked on.

However, when I replay "onclick" with "onload", it just stays at "500,500".

Why is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The element isn't loading any external content. Since there is nothing to load, it doesn't have a load event.

You can just run a script immediately after defining the circle element.

```
<circle ... />
<script> function_call() </script>
```

(the HTML `body` element is a special case, representing the current document)

Comment: When you say "function_call()", do you mean I literally type "setCoordinates(evt)" inside a pair of script tags?

Comment: Except for the `evt` bit since you don't have an actual event there. (You could replace it with a custom object if the function needs to access its properties)

Comment: No, sorry, doesn't work. Could you be a bit more specific please :/?

Comment: Surely I need to put the call inside the circle tag? Otherwise how does it know which circle I'm referring to?

Comment: Then give the circle an ID and reference it by ID rather than by `evt.target`.

Comment: <script type="text/ecmascript">
    <![CDATA[
    setCoordinates("c1");
    ]]>
    </script>

Comment: just after: <circle id="c1" cx="500" cy="500" r="25" fill="url(#grad1)" filter="url(#Screen)"/>

Answer (score 2):

On Firefox onload events are only dispatched to `<svg>` elements for performance reasons. Firefox has an existing bug about not dispatching onload events to `<image>` elements but at the moment only `<svg>` elements work cross-browser.

Answer (score 0):

I have this problems sometimes too with the onload event. 
Move your javascript call to the end of the page.